# Assign values to multiple rows based on condition

Tags: r

I'm working on a study where participants are assessed once per year. If the assessment began before 50 years of age, the participants should be assigned to the group "young". This definition is permanent, so if they are assessed again when they are ≥50, they should still be defined as "young". If they are assessed for the first time when they are ≥50, they are assigned to the group "old".

In other words, a participant can only be either young or old, they cannot switch from young to old during the study.

Right now, my data (>20000 rows) incorrectly look like this:

```
ID <- c("person1", "person1", "person2", "person3", "person3", "person3", "person4")
timepoint <- c(2020,2021,2018,2015,2016,2017,2021)
age <- c(49, 50, 45, 48, 49, 50, 55)
group <- c("young", "old", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old")
myinput <- data.frame(ID, timepoint, age, group)

>myinput
       ID timepoint age group
1 person1      2020  49 young
2 person1      2021  50   old
3 person2      2018  45 young
4 person3      2015  48 young
5 person3      2016  49 young
6 person3      2017  50   old
7 person4      2021  55   old
```

In row 2 and row 6, `group`is incorrect, as `person1` and `person3` are permanently defined as young, per the rule I stated above.

Essentially, I need R to check the list to see whether the persons are ever listed as `myinput$age < 50` and define `myinput$ = "young"` for all the rows with an individual `ID`, probably using `if else`.

Desired output:

```
       ID timepoint age group
1 person1         1  49 young
2 person1         2  50 young
3 person2         1  45 young
4 person3         1  48 young
5 person3         2  49 young
6 person3         3  50 young
7 person4         1  55   old
```

**Edit**: Thank you everyone for the helpful answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
myinput %>%
  mutate(
    group = if (any(age < 50)) "young" else "old",
    .by = ID
  )
#        ID timepoint age group
# 1 person1      2020  49 young
# 2 person1      2021  50 young
# 3 person2      2018  45 young
# 4 person3      2015  48 young
# 5 person3      2016  49 young
# 6 person3      2017  50 young
# 7 person4      2021  55   old
```

The use of `.by=` is a newer capability introduced in dplyr-1.1.0; if you have an older version and cannot upgrade, or if you are doing other grouped operations in surrounding operations, then instead use

```r
myinput %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    group = if (any(age < 50)) "young" else "old"
  )
```

## base R

(A little more work, same effect.)

```r
ifelse(
  ave(1:nrow(myinput), myinput$ID, FUN = function(z) any(myinput$age[z] < 50)),
  "young", "old")
# [1] "young" "young" "young" "young" "young" "young" "old"
```

and reassign that back to `myinput$group`.

The use of `ave` is a little more encumbered since the return value will always be coerced to the class of the first argument (`1:nrow(.)`). We can see that the inner function (`any(myinput$age[z] < 50)`) itself returns a logical, this is coerced as false=0 and true=1.

Answer (score 3):

Get `min`imum age per ID using `ave` and test if `< 50`. Adding `1L` to the resulting boolean coerces to integer, so we can subset `c('old', 'young')`.

```
> transform(myinput, g=c('old', 'young')[(ave(age, ID, FUN=min) < 50) + 1L])
       ID timepoint age group     g
1 person1      2020  49 young young
2 person1      2021  50   old young
3 person2      2018  45 young young
4 person3      2015  48 young young
5 person3      2016  49 young young
6 person3      2017  50   old young
7 person4      2021  55   old   old
```

If there are `NA`s in *group* we probably want `ave(age, ID, FUN=\(x) min(x, na.rm=TRUE))`.

---

*Data*

```
> dput(myinput)
structure(list(ID = c("person1", "person1", "person2", "person3", 
"person3", "person3", "person4"), timepoint = c(2020, 2021, 2018, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2021), age = c(49, 50, 45, 48, 49, 50, 55), 
    group = c("young", "old", "young", "young", "young", "old", 
    "old")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
myinput %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(correctGroup = ifelse(min(age)<50, "young","old"))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
# Groups:   ID [4]
  ID      timepoint   age group correctGroup
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>       
1 person1      2020    49 young young       
2 person1      2021    50 old   young       
3 person2      2018    45 young young       
4 person3      2015    48 young young       
5 person3      2016    49 young young       
6 person3      2017    50 old   young       
7 person4      2021    55 old   old
```